# Environment variable setup in mac for running a java application

Tags: macos, environment-variables, zsh

I am trying to setup a environment variable in OS X Yosemite. i am using zsh. 
i added

```
  export NEW_HOME=/Users/k/app/
```

and then loaded the file with

```
  source .profile or source .bash_profile
```

but when i restart the terminal it goes away. Then i added this to .zshrc file. It works. I can get the environment variable from terminal now. But the java application which requires this ENV value is not getting.

I really do not understand whats going on. Can u help me?

Comment: `zsh` is not a terminal, it is a shell.   Think of the terminal as a piece of hardware.

Comment: thansk @WilliamPursell. But can you help me to solve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables in OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: @RobNapier thats not working

Comment: Do you start the java application from the shell or via some other way (Finder for example)?

Comment: Unlike some other Unix systems, Mac OS X logins are not created from an initial shell environment. Ensuring that your Java app receives the correct  environment depends heavily on how you are starting it.

Comment: @Adaephon i am using GGTS to run the application

Answer (score 0):

Its solved by creating a environment.plist file in Library/Launchctl and seting the setenv inside string.

~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.launchd.conf.plist

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
      <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
           <key>Label</key>
             <string>local.launchd.conf</string>
               <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                 <array>
                   <string>setenv NEW_HOME /Users/k/app/</string>

                 </array>
               <key>RunAtLoad</key>
               <true/>
            </dict>
          </plist>
```

And after restating the Mac it started working.